# win10 64bit: computer sleeps within minutes of no activity

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I upgraded to win10 from win8 for my 64bit laptop. Everything is fine except the laptop sleeps very quickly. I went to the power management and even disabled sleep and this still occurs.

Has anyone seen this happen? How do I fix this?

Comment: if you downvote, please provide constructive criticism

Answer (score 0):

Try create a new power plan in power management.

Also, some laptops have their own software to control power plans (i.e. eco button on Toshiba), make sure you updated laptop manufacturer software as well.